# What is the date corresponding to a getTime with no hours , minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My program creates a unix time everyday :

```
(new Date(moment(jour, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY"),
          parseInt(moment(jour, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MM")) - 1,
          moment(jour, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD"), 0, 0, 0)).getTime();
```

Now there are many data in the database , and I want to know which date corresponds to a particular getTime. For example there is this data : 1571778000000. How to get the date of it ?

Comment: `var data = new Date(1571778000000)` you can use this.

Comment: use new Date(1571778000000) and then format the date using .toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JS date function

```js
const date = new Date(1571778000000);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: but the getMonth should be added 1 , isnt it ?

Comment: @pheromix `date.getMonth()` will give you one month less than the exact month. because of `getMonth()` calculates from 0

Answer (score 1):

"...represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC..."

see
[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(1571778000000)
```

returns the corresponding date on the current timezone

For a UTC date (GMT-0)

```
new Date(1571778000000).toUTCString()
```

returns "Tue, 22 Oct 2019 21:00:00 GMT"

Ps. Both Dates have equal values (same instant on time)